# Android - Replace lib jar with gradle jar

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gson, retrofit

I have gson2.2.4.jar in my android project folder(/libs/gson2.2.4.jar) and retrofit is conflicting with this. For that, I have to use gson 2.8.5 version. I cannot delete lib/gson2.2.4.jar as it is copied via a build tool. is there anyway override this libs folder version with gradle entry?

Thanks

Comment: Are there other jar files in libs directory?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should exclude like below:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', excludes: ['gson2.2.4.jar'], include: '*.jar')
```

Answer (score 0):

First delete your gson2.2.4.jar.

If you can't do that then follow this steps.

1. delete your `.gradle` and `.idea` folder from your project directory
2. Inside your project's `app` directory delete `build` directory.
3. Now delete your gson2.2.4.jar
4. Then Sync your project
5. add below dependency for retrofit2

```
  implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0'
  implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.0'
  implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.1'
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5' 

Hope this will helps you.
```

Comment: I cannot delete gson library from the library folder. It will again be copied because of the build tool, in which I dont have any control.

Comment: Just close Project and restart studio again. Once it Opens directly delete that .jar

Comment: It is cross platform tool, not android studio or eclipse. even if i delete this file, it will be again copied while building the apk.

Comment: Ohh. You didn't mention that here. As per your question my answer it right. Can you please appreciate that

Comment: I appreciate you for your time and help. But I mentioned in the question that I cannot delete the file from lib folder as it is copied via build tool. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need access your build tool code that is adding lib/gson2.2.4 and remove the logic which is adding that lib. If you don't have access or can't ask person who have access to that then what you can do is avoid gson from retrofit.

You can do that using following code:

```
implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:x.x.x') {

    exclude module: 'gson'
}
```

You need to review your code thoroughly if applying old version of a library do not causes any issues with Retrofit or your implementation.